# Is gpt_index override with llama_index?

Tags: llama-index, gpt-index

Recently I was working with one of my old code. While running it, it throws me an error msg.

```
from gpt_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTListIndex, GPTSimpleVectorIndex
```

Error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseLanguageModel' from 'langchain.schema'
```

Can someone help me to understand this one.

Comment: Try updating the llamaindex (earlier know as gpt index) version.